# C++ Hello world executed on AWS beanstalk

Tags: python, c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created a Python based web application on the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) instance. Now I want to execute a simple C++ executable from Python application (e.g. `application.py`)
I was able to pre-configure the instance with build-essential and g++, make, etc.
However, when I call my Hello world application through python application, I get internal server error.

In fact, I am seeking for a solution to run a C++ application on AWS beanstalk. My attempts include:

1. Building c++ file using Makefile through calling make command from `application.py` and then running it. (No success)
2. Building the executable and copying it to AWS EB and then run it. (No success)
3. Creating a FastCGI application to do the same thing. But I don't know how to deploy it on the AWS EB instance.

I know that C++ is not among the list of languages supported by AWS EB. But there should be a way to deploy a C++ executable on the cloud.

So, I'd appreciate any help or suggestions.

**Edit:**
Here is the code for `application.py`:

```
from flask import Flask
import subprocess as sp

def say_hello(username = "Hamid"):

    ll = []

    proc = sp.Popen(['make'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, bufsize=1)
    with proc.stdout:
        for line in proc.stdout:
            ll.append(line)  

    proc.wait()

    proc = sp.Popen(['./helloworld'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, bufsize=1)
    with proc.stdout:
        for line in proc.stdout:
            ll.append(line)    

    proc.wait()

    str_out = ""
    for l in ll:
        str_out += str(l) + "  "
    return '<p>Application output is: %s !</p>\n' % str_out

# some bits of text for the page.
header_text = '''
    <html>\n<head> <title>EB Flask Test</title> </head>\n<body>'''
instructions = '''
    <p><em>Hint</em>: This is a RESTful web service! Append a username
    to the URL (for example: <code>/Thelonious</code>) to say hello to
    someone specific.</p>\n'''
home_link = '<p><a href="/">Back</a></p>\n'
footer_text = '</body>\n</html>'

# EB looks for an 'application' callable by default.
application = Flask(__name__)

# add a rule for the index page.
application.add_url_rule('/', 'index', (lambda: header_text +
    say_hello() + instructions + footer_text))

# add a rule when the page is accessed with a name appended to the site
# URL.
application.add_url_rule('/<username>', 'hello', (lambda username:
    header_text + say_hello(username) + home_link + footer_text))

# run the app.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Setting debug to True enables debug output. This line should be
    # removed before deploying a production app.
    application.debug = True
    application.run()
```

Comment: Could you show your minimal hello world function and how you're calling it in application.py?

Comment: @SantiagoVarela I added the minimal code for `application.py`

Comment: This is giving you the internal server error and no more information?

Comment: @SantiagoVarela Yes.